# Is there anyway to monitor CLBeaconRegion without using CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cbcentralmanager, clbeaconregion, clbeacon

In my current app i am using

```
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])/
         [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    //self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:tempRegio
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
```

in this case nowhere i need to know user's location still my app asks that **it will use you current location even when you're not using this app**

Which is annoying for end user plus it constantly display purple arrow on the statubar indicating that the app uses GPS (Which it does not )

My question is

**Can we have mechanism where we can scan the beacon without use of CLLocationManager**

1 possible solution is to use CBCentralManager but i do not find a proper way where i can use it to detect beacons/ibeacons

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that the CLLocation manager is not tracking your location? It does constantly track your location to listen and detect if any beacons are in Range.

Comment: I am not getting that why app need to know my physical location to listen for beacon which is based on Bluetooth , BLE

Comment: @mihirmehta Beacon has a proximity value..That gives you range of your beacon..Thats why it needs your location.